# How can I upload images with text parameters using Flask

Tags: python, flask, http-post

I want to send a image together with some text parameters to a Flask server (HTTP POST).

How can I use Flask to receive both (e.g. save an image and print the text)?

Comment: I think you can get them from request.data

Comment: Have you seen http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access them from `request.data` just like any other form data.